# What exactly does argument of a function mean?

Tags: functions, terminology

What does argument of a function mean? I read Wiki etc and I'm still not sure.

Is Argument and Domain one and same thing?

If Domain corresponds to Range? Do we have a term corresponding to Argument too?

Comment: No, it's different.  The argument is not a set of possible values.

Comment: @William  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument is an element of the domain, as for example $f(x):A\to \mathbb{R}$ any $x\in A$ is an argument for the function.

The *argument* $x$ is also denoted as *input*, the value $y=f(x)$ is denoted as the *output* or the *image* of $x$ by $f$.

Comment: Do we have a term for something that assumes any value from range? Like as domain is to argument as range is to what?

Comment: @William I've added that, the value $y=f(x)$ is the output or image of $x$ by$ f$.

Comment: Sir, does that mean argument = pre-image?

Comment: The pre-image is a set of argument values, that is a subset of the domain, take a look here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pre-Image.html

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics) from what I understand after reading this, Image is basically Range? Oh crap, I'm just confusing myself even more!

Comment: the image of f is the set of all possible output values for the arguments in the domain, the image of x is the value y such that y=f(x)

Answer (score 2):

For a function $$f:A \to B $$ we call the set $A$ the *domain* of the function. $A$ is a set from which $f$ takes its arguments, and $B$ is the set where $f$'s outputs live.

The argument $x$ is an arbitrary representative of an element of $A$. For example, in the case, where $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = x^2$, $x$ is a representative for an arbitrary element $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The terminology differs a little depending on where you look. I prefer to say "$x$ is a point in the domain" and "$f(x) $ is a value in the range". *Points* in the domain map to *values* in the range.

Given a fixed value $y$, the preimage of $y \in B$ is the set $$ \{x \in A \mid y = f(x) \}$$

For a non-injective function, there will be a $y$ such that its preimage contains several points.